# Why use AppHarbor addons?

Tags: appharbor

Why should I use AppHarbor addons when I can get an account directly from the provider and have additional benefits (like multiple users or projects per account)? I know having addons per application centralizes configuration but it also means you have to go through AppHarbor.

In addition AppHarbor adds their header on the website of some providers (notably Airbrake), which ruins the design (looks out of place and has massive margins). On some addons pricing is much more flexible than the addon pricing (again, Airbrake is a good example - no idea what those plans offer!).

Comment: I've asked the AirBrake guys to update the plan descriptions. You can probably get a good idea of what the plans do by checking here: https://addons.heroku.com/airbrake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provisioning add-ons through AppHarbor gives you the advantages of automatic application configuration, consolidated billing and being able to manage everything from AppHarbor (and not having to remember X logins and not having to remember to keep X credit cards updated at various services providers).

We've tried to make make the header as inconspicuous as possible, and it seems to work well on most of our add-on partners sites. Please drop us a line at  if it causes breakage anywhere.

We're also continuously working with our add-on partners to keep their add-on plan offerings up-to-date and I've just shot the AirBrake guys an email. Thanks for alerting us to the problem!